# Why am I getting this error and how to resolve it : The multi-part identifier "SEQ.nextval" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I have been asked to create a SUPPLIER table consisting of two attributes namely SUPPLIER_ID and SUPPLIER_NAME and then to Create a sequence with min value 1, start with 101,increment by 1 ,max value 500. I am currently using Microsoft SQL Server and executed the following commands :-

This is the table and sequence I have created :-

```
create table SUPPLIER(SUPPLIER_ID int, SUPPLIER_NAME varchar(10))

create sequence SEQ
start with 101
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 500
```

I tried to insert into the table using the following command :

```
insert into SUPPLIER 
values(SEQ.nextval, 'Nilesh')
```

I am getting the following error:

The multi-part identifier "SEQ.nextval" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2):

NEXTVAL is not available in SQL Server.  Try the following

```
create sequence SEQ
start with 101
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 500;

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(
    SUPPLIER_ID int DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ) PRIMARY KEY
,   SUPPLIER_NAME varchar(10)
)


INSERT INTO T1 (SUPPLIER_ID , SUPPLIER_NAME )
    SELECT      NEXT VALUE FOR SUPPLIER_ID 
            ,   'Nilesh'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO T1 (SUPPLIER_NAME )
    SELECT      'Nilesh'
```